# how better code prefixes in MySQL tables with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to write PHP script, that uses table prefix for MySQL tables. Should I write all of requests like for example

```
$db_query='select * from '.$tbl_prefix.'sometable;';
```

or it's possible to set some variable, that will add this prefix to all queries?
For example, I'm performing request

```
$db_query='select * from sometable;';
```

and *MAGIC* adds prefix to table itself, so for MySQL query will look like

```
select * from pref_sometable;
```

Comment: It will be far too hard to do the string replacement ex post facto to insert your table prefix. Basically it could only work for the simplest queries. As soon as you have multiple joins or aliases, or the need to use dotted table names in your WHERE clause, you're going to have big difficulties.  Stick with your concatenation.

Comment: WHy do you need to use table prefixes? Why do you think it is mandatory and is always a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no MySQL command to do that, you must implement it in your code just like you do at first. So:

```
$db_query='select * from '.$tbl_prefix.'sometable;';
```

Is fine.

If you don't want to add a prefix on each query, you can create an object like this:

```
class database {
    function select($qry,$database) {
        $db_query="select " . $qry . " from myprefix_" . $database;
        // $res = query($db_query);
        return $res;
    }
}

$db_query=database->select("*","sometable");
// echo $db_query;
$db_query=database->select("playernick","sometable");
// echo $db_query;
```

That's not 100% PHP, it's just and idea so you can get it.

Answer (score 8):

Your first sample is the way to go; you'll need to prepend the prefix each time. It may make it easier to make this into a function though (incase you ever need to update anything, it would be far better to only have to update one location instead of multiple):

```
function _table($table) {
    global $tbl_prefix;
    return $tbl_prefix . $table;
}

$db_query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . _table('sometable') . ';';
```